# Como Contar La repeticion de una Palabra en C#

Tags: c#, string

Hola Buenas Tardes saben  he intentado por varias manera lograr encontrar la forma de contar la palabra que mas se repite en una oración y no logro solucionarlo

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una frase: ");
String texto =  Console.ReadLine();
```

- Cual fue la palabra que mas se repitió :
- Cuantas Veces se repitió dicha palabra:

Comment: No basta decir que lo intentaste , muéstranos que intentaste hasta ahora ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una frase: ");
        String texto = Console.ReadLine();
        String result = GetResultado(texto);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static string GetResultado(string linea)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> words = GetWordList(linea);

        var result = words
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(group => new { Word = group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count).FirstOrDefault();

        return "Palabra: "+ result.Word + " Cuenta: " + result.Count;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetWordList(string linea)
    {
        return linea.Split(' ').Where(st => !st.Equals(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una pequeña descripción del programa y cómo soluciona el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

ok primero debes utilizar el metodo de c# Split con el string que quieres analizar y le pasa como parametro un espacio en blanco (" "), para que este metodo debuelva un array con todas las palablras que contiene el string, e ir comparando laspalablras una por una aver cual se repite mas veces;

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una frase: ");
String texto =  Console.ReadLine();
String[] palabras = texto.Split(" ");
int[] nro_repeticion_palabra = new int[palabras.Length];



 for for (int i = 0; i < palabras.Length; i++)
{
    for for (int j = 0; j < palabras.Length; j++)
    {
        if (palabras[i].compareTo(palabras[j]) == 0 )
        {
            nro_repeticion_palabra[i]++;
        }
    } 
}
```

ahora solo faltaria ver en que posición del array (nro_repeticion_palabra) esta el número mayor y el valor que contenga esa posición es el numero de veces que se repite la palabra y en esa misma posición de ese array sera la palabra que mas se repite en el array (palabras).

Osea sin en el indice 3 (nro_repeticion_palabra[3] esta el número mayor supongamos que 5 entonces la palabra que mas se repite es la que esta en el palabras[3].

Es medio complicado...

Comment: Gracias a todos no entendi muy bien pero bueno si leo el codigo una y otravez demas me aprendo como utilizar bien el groupby.